# Get Bitmap with Picasso ILLEGAL_STATE_EXCEPTION

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, picasso

I try to get a Bitmap from a url that sent to Picasso in class that extends AsyncTask. 
It looks like this:

```
public class MoviesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

// Target object for Bitmap convert
private Target loadTarget;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private byte[] img;

public void getBitmap(String url){
    if (loadTarget == null)
        loadTarget = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                mBitmap = bitmap;
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }


        };
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(mContext);
    builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    builder.build().with(mContext).load(url).into(loadTarget);
}
```

The exception that I get is:
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should happen from the main thread.

Can't really understand what's the problem with my code and hope that anyone can help me with this one.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I tried to use .get() with Picasso and just insert it to Bitmap and it works.

Maybe will help someone else

```
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) throws IOException {
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(mContext);
    builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

   return mBitmap = builder.build().with(mContext).load(url).get();
}
```

Comment: Exception message says it all, you need to call async methods of Picasso, to avoid making network calls on UI thread.

Comment: Actually, quite the opposite, the exception says that `into` should be called from the UI thread. Which is a strange decision.